# Can't find toggle switch for location services

Tags: gnome, settings, gnome-control-center, geolocation

I am unable to find toggle switch to enable/disable location services.

[image: see here]

Answer (score 6):

With the default color scheme, I could not see the purple/black toggle a the top.

[image: oops]

Comment: This UI is so counter intuitive...